# When using laptop for heavy duty statistical analysis is it more important to have highest possible RAM or fastest possible processor?

Tags: memory, cpu, statistics

I'm starting a private equity company and need to buy a laptop that can  perform heavy duty statistical analysis. I don't know if I should focus on finding a laptop with the highest possible RAM or a very fast processor.

Comment: Neither. You should buy a server for that. Laptop CPUs and memory are optimized for low energy, not for heavy workloads. It also depends on what software you use (for some software, GPU might be more important that CPU).

Comment: Agreed you can buy a laptop. But set you up a sever/workstation with some decent specs. Maybe Multiple processors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of data. For large amounts of unpacked data with limited calculations, large amounts of RAM are recommended. For deep heavy-processing of smaller amounts of complex data, a good CPU should be priority. If the data really need very heavy processing, then a GPU-based approach is recommended, but software that can use GPU power for other than the designed intent is very rare and/or expensive and most of the time designed only to work on powerful servers, which brings us to the things mentioned in the comments: a server would be better for that purpose.
So to make a better recommendation, you should provide some details about what you want to process.